# Difference between going for and going on

Tags: word-choice

> 1. We went **for** a picnic on Sunday.
> 2. We went **on** a picnic on Sunday.

Which is correct to use?

Answer (score 1):

Both are in common use, but "to go **on** a picnic" [is more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=go+*+a+picnic&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3)

Otherwise the meaning is more or less the same.  There is a slight difference in *nuance* between "go for" and "go on":

> We went *for the purpose* of having a picnic
>
> We went *on a planned outing* that included a picnic.

However, in real-world conversations, it's too small a distinction to matter most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference in meaning if you are telling somebody what you did on Sunday. You can use either, but the former with the preposition "on" is more common.  However, sometimes the use of one preposition is preferable to the use of the other in reply to a questiom. For examples:

A- What did you do on Sunday?

B- we went on/for a picnic.

A- Why did you go to the seaside on Sunday?

B- we went for a picnic.